# convert an array of integers to an array of floats

Tags: python, numpy

Given any integer **n** convert it to a float **0.n**

```
#input
[11 22 5 1 68 17 5 4 558]
```

```
#output
[0.11  0.22  0.5   0.1   0.68  0.17  0.5   0.4   0.558]
```

Is there a way in numpy to do the following.

```
import numpy as np

int_=np.array([11,22,5,1,68,17,5,4,558])

float_=np.array([])
for i in range(len(int_)):
    float_=np.append(float_,int_[i]/10**(len(str(int_[i]))))
print(float_)
```

```
[0.11  0.22  0.5   0.1   0.68  0.17  0.5   0.4   0.558]
```

for now the code I have is slow (takes a lot of time for very large arrays)

Answer (score 3):

One way using `numpy.log10`:

```
arr = np.array([11,22,5,1,68,17,5,4,558])
new_arr = arr/np.power(10, np.log10(arr).astype(int) + 1)
print(new_arr)
```

Output:

```
[0.11  0.22  0.5   0.1   0.68  0.17  0.5   0.4   0.558]
```

Explain:

- `numpy.log10(arr).astype(int) + 1` will give you the number of digits
- `numpy.power(10, {above})` will give you the required denominator

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a **Vectorize** version of your code

```
def chg_to_float(val):
  return val/10**len(str(val))

v_chg_to_float = np.vectorize(chg_to_float)

np.array(list(map(chg_to_float, ar)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only inserting a `0.` in front of each input integer, you can simply cast them to strings, add the `0.`, and then cast them to floats.

```py
>>> input_list = [11, 22, 5, 1, 68, 17, 5, 4, 558]
>>> [float(f'0.{str(item)}') for item in input_list]
[0.11, 0.22, 0.5, 0.1, 0.68, 0.17, 0.5, 0.4, 0.558]
```

Performance could be enhanced by using a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension.