# convert an array of integers n0000 to 0.n0000

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Looking at this question,

[convert an array of integers to an array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73481160/convert-an-array-of-integers-to-an-array-of-floats)

My next question arose:

n00000 to 0.n00000

```
#input
arr = np.array([2,20,10,200,200000])
```

```
#output
array([0.2,0.20,0.10,0.200,0.200000])
```

My initial code:

```
np.array([f'0.{item}' for item in arr])
```

**I'm not** looking for an array of str,

```
#output
array(['0.2', '0.20', '0.10', '0.200', '0.200000'], dtype='<U8')
```

but a floating array that contains all the zeros, without resorting to a **for** that goes through one by one since this is very slow for very large arrays.

```
#output
array([0.2,0.20,0.10,0.200,0.200000])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `log10` with `ceil` to find the magnitude of each number (+1 to handle the exact multiples of 10) and divide by the matching power of 10:

```
arr = np.array([2,20,10,200,200000])

out = arr/10**np.ceil(np.log10(arr+1))
# or with floor:
# arr/10**(np.floor(np.log10(arr))+1)
```

output: `array([0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])`

*NB. you can't have the trailing zeros in python with floats, this is just impossible.*

##### reversing the operation

this is impossible if you don't keep track of the powers (leading zeros are not significant).

With the powers:

```
arr = np.array([2,20,10,200,200000])
pwr = 10**np.ceil(np.log10(arr+1))
out = arr/pwr
# array([0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])


# reverse operation
arr2 = (out*pwr).astype(int)
# array([     2,     20,     10,    200, 200000])
```

Comment: thanks, but keep in mind that zeros are lost, what I'm looking for is this: `array([0.2,0.20,0.10,0.200,0.200000])`

Comment: @EstudianteInversa this is impossible unless you use strings, trailing zeros are not meaningful in python: `print(0.200)` -> `0.2`

Comment: that's clear that's why I have the doubt!

Comment: I just realize the link in your question…glad we have the same approach :D

Comment: Why would you need this anyway?

Comment: to then do the reverse process in a later operation!

Comment: Then, again, that's not possible with this single list. You can save the powers however. Let me update

Comment: An why are you doing this back and forth conversion? (what is the underlying goal?)